# Copy folder + append datetimestamp in S3 using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Does anyone know how to copy a whole folder to s3 and append date and timestamp to that folder?Example, when I run this command:

```
 aws s3 cp sourcefolder s3://somebucket-test-bucket/ --recursive
```

Then in my bucket I want to see "sourcefolder+datetimestamp" uploaded. That way my folder doesn't get overwritten as it has a unique name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that using the CLI, unless you provide the timestamp as part of the parameters.

bash example:
`aws s3 cp sourcefolder s3://my-bucket/foldername+$(date +"%d-%m-%y")/`